# Which of a,b,c,d is/are odd given the set of conditions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to answer this question.

Which of a,b,c,d is/are odd given the set of conditions?

Condition 1.) ad + bc is odd

Condition 2.) ac + bd is odd

The question is actually asking if we can uniquely determine which of a,b,c,d are odd/even using $$\\$$
a.) one of the given conditions individually but not the other$$\\$$
b.) either one condition individually$$\\$$
c.) both conditions combined $$\\$$
d.) Not at all$$\\$$
It is given that a,b,c,d are positive integers greater than 0.

My solution:

Since ad + bc is odd, one of then is odd and the other even. If a is even that would make both b and c odd while d can be even or odd.

Since this condition gives multiple possibilities it cannot give a unique answer.

Same reasoning goes to condition 2 also.

Even both combined we cannot have a unique answer so my answer is option

d.) Not at all

But the answer in the book to the question is option a.) can be answered by one of the given conditions individually but not the other.

Can anyone explain how this is? I am unable to understand.

Thanks in advance

Vikrant

Comment: $a,b,d$ odd and $c$ even give $ad+bc$ odd and $ac+bd$ odd. But $a,b,c$ odd and $d$ even also give $ad+bc$ odd and $ac+bd$ odd. So a), b), and c) must be wrong.

Comment: Knowing both conditions, one variable is even and the rest are odd.

Comment: Thanks guys, That was my conclusion as well. One of the three is odd and the rest are even, but we cannot pinpoint which one exactly is odd.